# Rails Action Mailer SMTPAuthenticationError: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am setting up my ActionMailer but an authentication error occurs whenever I try to send an email. Here are my SMTP Settings.

```
 config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   address:              "smtp.gmail.com",
   port:                 587,
   domain:               "gmail.com",
   user_name:            ENV["SMTP_USERNAME"],
   password:             ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
   authentication:       "plain"
 }
```

I also looked extensively at the related questions and tried a few solutions, namely:

- Change authetication plain to login
- Enable less secure apps on gmail
- Disable captcha

Hope someone could help out!

Comment: Did you check that ENV variable contains correct credentials ?

Comment: Yes it does! I actually tried putting the details in plain text, that worked. Although I’m not quite sure why ENV variables don’t work.

Comment: A pro-tip is to use `ENV.fetch("KEYNAME")` every time you have a required ENV var as it will raise an easy to troubleshoot error when booting Rails instead of later when the configuration is used.

Comment: try adding `enable_starttls_auto: true` or changing port to `465`

Comment: Thanks @max for the tip. This worked!